# postgres: Index not being used or how to optimize

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with an index on a boolean field ("test"). When it's the true, it uses the index so it's loads fast but when it's false it doesn't use it. Is something wrong?

I have here the explain analyze of it:

```
DB_development=# explain analyze SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_test" = 't';
                                                                      QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=22890.67..22890.68 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1848.655..1848.656 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_is_test on users  (cost=0.00..22846.51 rows=17665 width=0) (actual time=34.727..1844.081 rows=21457 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (is_test = true)
         Filter: is_test
 Total runtime: 1848.882 ms
(5 rows)

DB_development=# explain analyze SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_test" = 'f';
                                                      QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=84505.74..84505.75 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=9557.632..9557.632 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..84063.72 rows=176807 width=0) (actual time=71.653..9533.595 rows=219531 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT is_test)
 Total runtime: 9557.655 ms
(4 rows)
```

**UPDATE**

I saw here [Adding an index on a boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539772/adding-an-index-on-a-boolean-field) that it can ignore indexes... I think it's right cause the non test users are actually quite a lot compared to test users.

```
DB_development=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_test" = 't';
 count
-------
 21457
(1 row)

DB_development=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_test" = 'f';
 count
--------
 219531
(1 row)
```

if that's the case... how can I do a quick count then?

**Update**

Here's the create table and indexes:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "genre_id"
    t.integer  "country_id"
    t.boolean  "is_test",                                          :default => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"

    ... + 90 more fields (it's my main table)
  end

  add_index "users", ["country_id"], :name => "index_users_on_country_id"
  add_index "users", ["genre_id"], :name => "index_users_on_genre_id"
  add_index "users", ["is_test"], :name => "index_users_on_is_test"

  ... + 17 more indexes
```

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement including all defined indexes.

Comment: Added SQL information.

Comment: That's not SQL you added. What language is that?

Comment: Oh. Yeah right. That is the schema.db from Rails (Ruby). XD

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why index might not be used. Table is too small. The column/value combo is not selective enough. PostgreSQL "thinks" that it will be faster to scan another way.

I described them with more details and examples in [this blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/2010/09/09/why-is-my-index-not-being-used/).

Answer (score 2):

If you `SET enable_seqscan = off` (only for testing purposes, do not set that in `postgresql.conf` or use it in production, as it'll make other queries massively slower) and re-test, you'll probably find that the `false` case is *slower* when forced to use an index.

Personally I would drop the index and instead add a partial index on `(is_test) WHERE (NOT is_test)`.

I'd also consider making other heavily used indexes partial on `WHERE (NOT is_test)` if that's a common pattern, as it'll greatly speed the non-test index use.

Anyway, if the `SET enable_seqscan = off` case is *faster* (rather unlikely) then your `random_page_cost` is might be too high.

Also, if you were using PostgreSQL 9.2 you'd probably get a better plan for the true case; it would usually be able to use an index-only scan to avoid scanning the table at all. If the index is small enough relative to the table and vacuum is running aggressively enough it might even use an index-only scan for the false case, too, since it'd have to read so much less data. Since your table is hugely wide (90 fields) this seems quite likely. So consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

This seems perfectly normal... Per the row counts, the true value yields roughly 10% of the rows; false yields the remaining 90%. In the latter case, it's faster to read the entire table than to go back and forth following the index. (It's not selective enough to be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cost parameter settings are at their default, your table is about 84063.72-1768 pages, or 640 MB.  (verify with \d+)

If it takes 9 seconds to scan that much data, either your server is terribly overloaded, or the data is not cached and it has to be read from disk.

You can get better info by turning on track_io_timing and then redoing the query with "explain (analyze, buffers) select ...."