# Applying methods in ActiveRecord query with joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to retrieve a list of clients who's last `state_change` has a `to_state_id` equal to the value of the `type` argument (in `self.filter_by`).

I have already defined a method called `current_state` which retrieves the current `to_state` of a client, but I am unsure of how to apply this in a query.
I have also tried to use `state_changes.last.to_state_id` in a query but that fails as it thinks 'last' is a table, when it is actually a method.

My relations are as follows. A `client` has many `state_changes`, and a `state_change` has a `from_state` and a `to_state`.

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :from_states,  class_name: 'StateChange', foreign_key: :from_state_id
  has_many :to_states,    class_name: 'StateChange', foreign_key: :to_state_id
end

class StateChange < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :from_state, class_name: "State", foreign_key: :from_state_id
    belongs_to :to_state,   class_name: "State", foreign_key: :to_state_id
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many                :state_changes

  def current_state
    state_changes.last.to_state
  end

  def self.filter_by(type)
    # querying for clients which have a current_state with id equal to type
    joins(:state_changes).where('state_changes.last.to_state_id=?', type)
  end
end
```

I am fairly new to ActiveRecord and ruby so be gentle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may very well be possible with Rails query, but given the performance hit you'd take and potential to add it to other queries, I recommend you cache the current value somewhere. Here are a couple options...

1) You can add a column to the client and set it whenever the client state changes.  You do this `after_create` on the state_change model.

In the migration

```
add_column :clients, :current_state_id, :integer
```

And point to the state record that is the current state.

```
def self.filter_by(type)
  where(:current_state => type )
end
```

2) Or, you can add a `current` boolean to the state_changes table and set it when current state changes.  You can put an index on this, and set a has_one on client

```
has_one :current_state, -> { where(current: true) }, class_name => "StateChange"
```

This is how you add a partial index to a boolean column:

[Adding an index on a boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539772/adding-an-index-on-a-boolean-field)

If you did this, you'd then query like so:

```
def self.filter_by(type)
  joins(:current_state).where(:state_changes { :to_state_id => type })
end
```

In your case,  I'd pick #1.  It feels like current state could be on the client and you'd use that a lot.

Comment: Option 2 is most viable, but it seems like extra effort, because the current state is already retrieved as the `last` or 'most recent' `state_change` record for that client, which is effectively the same as setting a boolean for each `state_change` to determine which is the latest/current state

Comment: Option 2 has proven to work, although I had to modify the syntax a little:    `joins(:current_state_change).where('state_changes.to_state_id = ?', type)`

Comment: The reason you do that is so you can join without sorting.  It also means you can "include" that value if you actually need it - like to show the `state.name` in a list.  If you do take option 2, I also would add a callback somewhere in state_changes to ensure there is always one and only one 'current' state per client.